Clarification on the proof of single choice
Recently been reading Terence Tao's Analysis I. There is a statement in the proof that I can't figure out the logic behind it. How did he get to x ∈ A ⇐⇒ x ∈ ∅ from x doesn't belong to ∅ and A?
Axiom 3.2 (Empty set). There exists a set ∅, known as the empty set,
which contains no elements, i.e., for every object x we have x not ∈ ∅.
Lemma 3.1.6 (Single choice). Let A be a non-empty set. Then there
exists an object x such that x ∈ A.
We prove by contradiction. Suppose there does not exist any
object x such that x ∈ A. Then for all objects x, we have x not ∈ A. Also,
by Axiom 3.2 we have x not∈ ∅. Thus x ∈ A ⇐⇒ x ∈ ∅ (both statements
are equally false), and so A = ∅ by Definition 3.1.4(Equality of sets), a contradiction.

Yeah, this can be confusing. What is basically happening is that, when we assume the contrary, we have that for all $x,$ both the statements $x\notin A$ and $x\notin \emptyset$ holds. And from the way implication is defined, this gives us $x\notin A \iff x\notin \emptyset.$ Take the contrapositive of this to get $x\in A \iff x\in \emptyset.$

@aqualubix Thank you so much!
